# Missing props with HOC and TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I've been having this problem for quite some time now and I've run out of ideas.

I want to create a HoC that will add some props (functions and strings) to the original component. So far I have this:

**Decorator:**

```
import * as React from "react";

export interface TestDecoratorProps {
  sayHello: () => void;
}

const withTestDecorator = <P extends TestDecoratorProps>(
  Component: React.ComponentType<P>,
): any => (props: Pick<P, Exclude<keyof P, keyof TestDecoratorProps>>) => {
  const sayHello = () => {
    console.log("hello");
  };

  return <Component {...props as P} sayHello={sayHello} />;
};

export default withTestDecorator;
```

**Usage:**

```
import * as React from "react";
import withTestDecorator, { TestDecoratorProps } from "@decorators/TestDecorator";

interface Props extends TestDecoratorProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

@withTestDecorator
class Paragraph extends React.Component<Props> {
  public componentDidMount() {
    this.props.sayHello();
  }

  public render() {
    return <p>{this.props.children}</p>;
  }
}

export default Paragraph;
```

**And implementation:**

```
class Application extends React.Component {
  public render(): React.ReactNode {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Paragraph>Hello</Paragraph>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

My problem is, in implementation, `Paragraph` throws an error saying that is requires `sayHello` prop. What can I do?

I am on TypeScript 3.4.3 and React 16.8.6.

Comment: Decorators can't change class structure. Try calling the hoc directly `export default  withTestDecorator(Paragraph)`

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir wrapper works just fine, but I want to use decorators to avoid having multiple wrappers.

Comment: This is a design limitation, doesn't matter what the decorator returns the type of the class that it decorates remains unaffected. TS just doesn't do this (I know JS decorators can replace the original definition, but TS does not model this)

Comment: If you want to have multiple wrappers, use `compose`. As for decorators, this is unsupported, as it was said. Also this provides wrong semantics because `Paragraph` is not a class at all, this may become a problem for testing.

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir yes, I am coming from JS decorators, where such usage was normal. Well, thank you for this information nevertheless ;)

Comment: @estus: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Usually it's expected from a decorator that the result is decorated class. In your case `Paragraph` is an arrow. If you ever need to extend or test `Paragraph` *class*, this cannot be done.

Comment: @estus I tried using class as well, same result. It seems that TS doesn't support such things. Can you elaborate on `compose`?

Comment: `compose` function from Redux, Recompose or other utility libs. It allows to write multiple HOCs (which withTestDecorator actually is) without nesting. See https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#compose

Comment: @estus Thank you, I've completely forgot about this!